# Android Studio Layout: reduce size of padding around button label

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

How do I make the width of a button smaller than the default size as setup in Android studio?

For example, two basic button looks like this:

[image]

The layout for these buttons is:

[image]

I'd like to reduce the amount of "padding" to the right and left of the button label. I'd like the "Ok" button to be less wide. It shouldn't be the same length as the "Cancel" button. Seems that by default Android Studio is making the buttons the same width.

Comment: `Button`'s have an `android:minWidth` default that causes that. You can set a desired value for that attribute yourself, either directly on the `<Button>` elements, or in a style assigned to `android:buttonStyle` in the theme used there.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you!

Comment: Plese do not put code in image cause it is hard to copy and paste.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule Roger!